# Definition of Sievert (Sv) unit - is it whole body mass?

Tags: radiation, units, biophysics

I'm wondering about the definition of the [Sievert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sievert)  (Sv) unit. It is J/Kg but is that Kg the mass of the whole body or just of the exposed body part? For instance, when a table says that an x-ray of a limb gives a dose of 0.1 mSv, does that mean that the body has been committed to 0.1 * N J of energy where N is the weight of the limb (in kg)? Or is N the mass of the whole body (so that the dose received by the limb in question is actually greater)?

It's a bit strange that this is J/Kg because people readily translate the radiation dose into a cancer risk (saying a dose of X mSv increases cancer risk by Y%), since I would assume the risk must depend not only on the radiation dose per unit of mass, but also on the amount of mass exposed to this level of radiation, i.e. related more to the actual J than to J/Kg?

Comment: Note that, in the regime where risk is proportional to exposure, it makes sense to normalize by only the exposed mass, since overall risk is also proportional to exposed area. That is, if a given amount of grays/rads is absorbed, you want the equivalent dose in sieverts/rems to be the same whether it was a large exposure over a small area or a lesser exposure over a larger area. This is why the USNRC [can say](http://www.nrc.gov/about-nrc/radiation/health-effects/measuring-radiation.html) "For practical purposes, 1 R (exposure) = 1 rad (absorbed dose) = 1 rem or 1000 mrem (dose equivalent)."

Answer (score 4):

The Sievert is a derived measure of stochastic health risk.  It's used only in cases of low dosage ionizing radiation.  High dosages that produce deterministic health effects are measured in the Gray (Gy), a purely physical term which represents the actual deposit of one joule of energy in one kilogram of matter.

Unlike the Gray, the Sievert does not measure an actual deposit of energy into tissue.  The Sievert is an *equivalent* dose which represents the likelihood of the effect of depositing one joule of energy in one kilogram of matter.  The Sievert is used to calculate an *equivalent* dose, which is computed using the actual deposited dose multiplied by a weighting factor which depends on the type of ionizing radiation to which one has been exposed.

The Sievert also is used to measure *effective* dose, which takes into consideration the biological susceptibility of the particular targeted tissue.  If you go to this link: http://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_difference_between_Sievert_and_Gray_A_practical_question_concerning_the_SI_units_for_ionizing_radiation, and scroll down to Jean Louis M. Genicot's comment, you will find he discusses the ways in which the Sievert is used, and how it is differentiated from the Gray.  This chart summarizes the relationship between *equivalent* and *effective* dose: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/03/SI_Radiation_dose_units.png.

In making these calculations, the intensity of radiation (microSieverts per hour, for example), rather than the mass of the tissue irradiated, is the basis for determining risk.  This link is  a comparative chart of exposures and risks: http://www.radiologyinfo.org/en/info.cfm?pg=safety-xray.  However, note at the bottom of the chart that "actual dose can vary substantially, depending on a person's size".  In other words, volume is important because it may determine how much ambient radiation is absorbed.

If your whole body is exposed to ionizing radiation, then your weight is a proxy for your volume.  But if the radiation is directed only at one area of tissue, with no leakage to the surrounding area, only the targeted area tissue should be used in the calculation.  The Wikipedia article on Equivalent Dose has a section that discusses this (scroll down to "Related Quantities"): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalent_dose.

Comment: Could you provide a reference for the information you give? That would make this a very useful answer.

Comment: @Floris:  I added references, and found I had to modify the answer.

Comment: Very nice. Note also that different organs have different radiation sensitivities - so if you are really trying to evaluate "risk" you definitely start with "dose per volume irradiated", then multiply by the organ specific "tissue weighting" factor before coming up with a total risk (effective dose). Effective, equivalent... many different ways to slice the pie. But in reality we don't know all that much.

Comment: Hi thanks but I'm actually still a bit unsure about it. I already knew this about the dose being weighted based on type of radiation etc. when converting from Gray to Sievert. But it doesn't substantially change my "difficulty" with the concept of J/Kg as being used as a unit of risk (i.e. proportional to actual risk). Imagine that there's only one type of radiation with weighting factor 1, and that only one organ type is exposed with weight 1, then Gray's should equal Sievert. But I still think J/Kg must be the wrong measurement of risk. I think the risk is more likely to depend on just

Comment: ... total energy absorbed, i.e. Joule. Because if one cell turns cancerous, it doesn't matter how many other cells you have, it is not like the effect is "dilluted" by having more other cells. If we make the (probably somewhat wrong) assumption that cancer risk is directly proportional to number of DNA-damage events, i.e. a simple "One-hit" model) where every radiation ray/particle absorbed will carry some fixed risk independent of all the other particles. If we were to measure the risk of a person that had been exposed to radiation, clearly we would never consider "J/Kg". After all, what...

Comment: ... does the size of the person have to do with it. It is simply the total number of absorptions, and hence the amount of energy absorbed that counts, hence J.

Comment: @Morty:  A joule absorbed by a few cells results in greater radiation per cell than a joule absorbed by many cells.  If an elephant absorbs a joule of energy, it does not mean a focused beam of energy hits only a narrow area of the elephant.

Comment: @Ernie: Yes I'm aware of that. But risk-wise (according to current LNT models) isn't it equivalent. I.e. cancer risk is the same if 10 cells absorbing 100 particles each, compared to 20 cells absorbing 50 particles each? I'm aware more complex risk models would come to a different result, but this would not be captured by the "Sv" unit either. In either case it seems wrong to focus on J/Kg rather than just J.

Comment: @Morty It seems to me that J/Kg is a way to get back to real data, instead of relying on an unrealistic LNT model: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2663584/

Comment: @Ernie: I agree it would have that effect but wondering if that is the objective... because almost all official bodies advocate LNT.

Comment: @Morty: ". . . at low doses the (epidemiological) data are imprecise and often conflicting" (from article cited in my previous comment).  Effects of low doses of ionizing radiation are primarily stochastic, rather than deterministic (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2663578/).  LNT is a cautious (erring toward safety) approximation.   But stochastic methods, it seems to me,  are made more precise by using J/kg.  The official bodies may want to err on the side of safety.